# How to save select query results within temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to save select query output into temporary table. Then I need to make another select query against this temporary table. Does anybody know how to do it?

I need to make this on SQL Server.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can also do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
    Column1 type1,
    Column2 type2,
    Column3 type3
)

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE
SELECT ...

SELECT *
FROM #TEMPTABLE ...

DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: Can you please clarify, is this temporary table really located on HDD, or it's just a runtime projection? And what would happen if I don't delete this temporary table?

Comment: The table is in a temp database and is only visible to the connection that created it.  Once that connection is gone or the stored procedure finishes, the temp table goes away.

Comment: You don't even need to mention CREATE TABLE command, all you can do is run simple SELECT query and at end type INTO #TempTable and whatever fields you've selected goes into #TempTable creating columns and types automatically

Answer (score 65):

```
select *
into #TempTable
from SomeTale

select *
from #TempTable
```

Comment: The # in front of #TempTable indicates it's a temp table.

Comment: When this table would be dismissed?

Comment: #TempTable lasts within the session that creates it. Once the session is closed, it's gone. Also it can only be accessed within the same session. No other sessions can see and access it. There is another type of temp table ##TempTable (notice ##) which has a global scope. It can be seen and accessed from other sessions, therefore ##TempTable is unique (no one can create another with the same name). Server restarts, ##TempTable is gone.

Comment: Each session can create its own #TempTable without running into name clashing.

Comment: like this but better I think is

```sql
    select *
    into temp temptable
    from sometable;

    select *
    from temptable;
```

Comment: This is a much better approach to creating #TempTable ... less line of code

Answer (score 2):

In `Sqlite`:

```
CREATE TABLE T AS
SELECT * FROM ...;
-- Use temporary table `T`
DROP TABLE T;
```