# How to save query result when using SQL in R?

Tags: sql, r, save

If just SQL, we can use the following code to save a query result in a temporary table, so that we can use the result later.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
    Column1 type1,
    Column2 type2,
    Column3 type3
)

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE
SELECT ...

SELECT *
FROM #TEMPTABLE ...
```

This answer is from [How to save select query results within temporary table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391442/how-to-save-select-query-results-within-temporary-table) 
However, I am using R to connect HANA. I need to use SQL query in R to select data from HANA. I need a tempory table for my query result. My code is like this:

```
sqlQuery(ch,paste('
                  CREATE TABLE #myTemp(
                     "/BIC/ZSALE_OFF"   INT
                  )
                  INSERT INTO #myTemp
                  SELECT
                  "/BIC/ZSALE_OFF"
                  FROM
                  "SAPB1D"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212"
                  '))
```

I have got the following error information:

```
[1] "42000 257 [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near \"INSERT\": line 5 col 19 (at pos 124)"                                                                                                                                                                                            
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect '\n                  CREATE TABLE #myTemp(\n                     \"/BIC/ZSALE_OFF\"   INT\n                  )\n                  INSERT INTO #myTemp\n                  SELECT\n                  \"/BIC/ZSALE_OFF\"\n                  FROM\n                  \"SAPB1D\".\"/BIC/AZ_RT_A212\"\n
```

Without the temperory result part, the code for just query is correct:

```
sqlQuery(ch,paste('
                  SELECT
                  "/BIC/ZSALE_OFF"
                  FROM
                  "SAPB1D"."/BIC/AZ_RT_A212"
                  '))
```

I am not sure if the grammar is correct, or there is something else I do not understand.

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using and are you certain that your syntax is correct for that database?

Comment: Hi, I am using R to connect HANA. I need to use SQL query in R to select data from HANA. So, I do not know the version of SQL. I am nore sure if my grammar is correct. This might be the reason.

Comment: Can't you just assign it to an R variable with `<-`?

Comment: Usually I can assign it to an R variable with <-. But sometimes, the data frame is too big for my computer, So I think this is not the best way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using the `dbplyr` package? If you already have a connection to a SQL database there isn't much more work to do.